# Android - Auto-complete from ListView with 2 textView

Tags: android, listview, autocomplete

In my App there is a "Search" area with an Auto-complete edit text and listView.
At each item (Songs in my case) of the listView I have 2 textView, but my Auto-complete search line dosnt work.

Here is my code:

```
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSearchList);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAutoComplete);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(
            this,
            songs
    );
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            SearchSongs.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Each time I enter sequence text nothing change.
Thanks

Comment: Song is an Array with the fields - songName and songArtists (the two textView)

Answer (score 0):

check this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete

after search you have a new adapter, you need to call `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` again for refreshing your listview, also`notifyDataSetChanged()` may help

Comment: The link you post talk about simple textView, not ListView. and I think that the proble is thae auto-complete search dont know where to look (the first textview or the second), and then I dont know how to filtter the list

Comment: autoCompeteTextView is kind of EditText and provides suggestions.  
so what do we have here? a EditText that it's text used for Searching and a listView with two textViews?  
next question is what do you search for? and autoCompleteTextView suggests what?